# Compactness of $[0,+\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Let's say we have $$F = [0,∞).$$

1. How can we determine whether this is a compact set or not?
2. And let's say we have $U = {(-1,n)}$ ($n∈N$), book said that this $U$ is the open cover of $F$, but I thought $U$ is not a subset of $F$, so it can not be an open subset of $F$?

Correct my thoughts please.

thank you

Answer (score 2):

Open cover of space $F$ is a family $\mathcal U = \{U_i\}_{i\in\mathbb I}$ of open sets such that $\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb I}U_i = F$. So $\mathcal U$ is not a subset of $F$, but every element of $\mathcal U$ is. To show that a space is not compact it is enough to find open cover for which no finite subcover exists. Just consider cover given in (2). Is there open subcover of it?

Comment: I think the OP was also bothered with the fact that $(-1,n)$ isn't a subset of $F$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: @PhilippeMalot: yeah, you might be right. But on the other hand OP wrote "but i thought U is not a subset of F" and earlier denoted cover as U. Hard to tell really

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like in the book you're thinking about $F$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. So then you can also consider the set $U$ as you've defined, since each element $I \in U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $U$ covers $F$.

Of course, if you wanted to think of $F$ as the whole topological space you're working with (*i.e.*, not as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$), you can take the open cover $U$ of $F$ from $\mathbb{R}$ and intersect its elements with $F$. In other words, we can consider $U' = \{I \cap F : I \in U\} = \{\lbrack 0, n) :  n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. It's immediate (and easy to see directly) that this is an open cover of $F$ in the subspace topology.